# oapi-codegen gin server append error with c.Error() instead of dumping it with c.JSON()

Tags: go, openapi, openapi-generator, go-gin

This is the command I'm using to generate the gin server:

```
oapi-codegen -generate gin,types,spec -package api api/openapi/api.yaml > internal/api/openapi/api.go
```

When the gin server code is generated, it provides a wrapper for the service interface. This wrapper does some request validation logic; however, when it encounters an error, it dumps it to the response payload...

```
// FindPetById operation middleware
func (siw *ServerInterfaceWrapper) FindPetById(c *gin.Context) {
    ...
    err = runtime.BindStyledParameter("simple", false, "id", c.Param("id"), &id)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"msg": fmt.Sprintf("Invalid format for parameter id: %s", err)})
        return
    }
    ...
}
```

What is expected is...

```
// FindPetById operation middleware
func (siw *ServerInterfaceWrapper) FindPetById(c *gin.Context) {
    ...
    err = runtime.BindStyledParameter("simple", false, "id", c.Param("id"), &id)
    if err != nil {
        c.Error(err)
        return
    }
    ...
}
```

...this way a middleware can handle the error. Is there a way to either:

1. Generate the wrapper so it behaves as ☝️ ?
2. Omit the wrapper and implement the validation myself?

I've also submitted an issue with the maintainers: https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen/issues/584

Pull request here: https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen/pull/587

Comment: If it helps anyone, which it did for me, you can actually override the templates with your own: https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen#making-changes-to-code-generation